# New to Oracle Coherence, trying to put data into the cache, two machines one server one client

Tags: oracle-coherence

I am new to Oracle Coherence, coming most recently from the Hadoop/Accumulo world

My basic goal: I have two laptops each running an CentOS VM, one is going to run a cache server, and the other will be a client that will put data in the cache.

At the most basic level how would I accomplish this? I just need a point in the right direction and I can take off from there. Been under the weather and through an insomnia bout so my thinky bits are not working at full capacity.

Run a modified cache-server script, and set up the client to point to the remote cache server, maybe using Extends? Do I need Weblogic or can I just run the cache server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you want to run at least 3 cache servers. (Remember, it's an HA cluster. A cluster of 1 isn't much of an HA cluster.)

Since the servers are naturally embeddable, they are often run co-located as part of an application server, such as WebLogic. In that case, there is no separate "client" per se, because code running on any application server can call the Coherence API locally to access any of the data managed in Coherence.

To access the data from another process that is not running Coherence (i.e. does not have a Coherence server embedded in the process, i.e. is not part of the Coherence cluster itself), then you would use Coherence*Extend, which is the client/server protocol to connect into a Coherence cluster. See: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHCG/gs_configextend.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw documentation on Oracle extends and have been trying to run the "demo" TestClient application from my client (for reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15357_01/coh.360/e15726/gs_example.htm).          
For the demo application when starting up cache servers the docs say need to have the client application on the cache server classpath:    
    java -cp COHERENCE_HOME\coherence.jar;PATH_TO_CLIENT -Dtangosol.coherence.cacheconfig=PATH\example-config.xml com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer    
With the client running completely separate...this doesn't make sense to me

Comment: The application often needs to be in the server class path so that the application classes (key and value objects) can be deserialized on the server for back-end processing.